# How to control the number of characters for the SHA1 displayed in Magit's log view?

Tags: magit

I've noticed some repositories use 7 characters, others 11 when displaying a SHA1.

It looks as if magit uses the output of `git log --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit` however I can't see how to configure this to behave differently.

---

#### Incomplete Solutions

**Call with arguments**

If I call `(magit-log-current nil (list "--abbrev=12"))` then the log shows at least 12 characters. However refreshing the log view looses the setting.

**Set the initial arguments**

This also works before refreshing resets the value and looses the SHA1 length I had set.

```el
(put 'magit-log-mode 'magit-log-current-arguments
     (cons "--abbrev=12" (get 'magit-log-mode 'magit-log-default-arguments)))
(call-interactively 'magit-log-current)
```

---

Is there a way to control how many characters I used to display the SHA1 hash in Magit's log view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that using advice isn't ideal, however I couldn't find a way to do this that didn't involve changing my personal git configuration.

---

This can be done by adding advice to `magit-log-arguments`.

```el
(defvar my-magit-log-sha1-size 16)
(defun my-magit-log-arguments-extra (fn-orig &optional mode)
  (pcase-let ((`(,args ,files) (funcall fn-orig mode)))
    (list (append args (list (format "--abbrev=%d" my-magit-log-sha1-size))) files)))

(advice-add 'magit-log-arguments :around #'my-magit-log-arguments-extra)
```

Answer (score 1):

In a shell, do

```bash
git config --global core.abbrev 12
```

or use `--local` to set it per project.

You'll have to recreate the log buffer to enable the change.

Comment: Is there a way to do this that only impacts magit? This is needed for a package I maintain and I don't want users of this package to have to modify their local git configuration.

Comment: I don't know much about magit (although you seem to have found a way to do it). OTOH, you can do `--local` to have it done per project, rather than globally.